# Select users with conditional counts in a date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having a problem to write a select to a following table:

| user_id | email | user_name | task_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 123@email.ru | user_user | 456 | approve (or decline) | 2021-03-3121:11:10.367485 |

I need to make a select for dates 1.03 to 31.03 for each user (name, email and id) to show how many tasks he did in total, how may of them were approved and how many were declined.

Comment: And what is the problem, exactly? What was your attempt and what went wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.You should show the table structure first by
`\d table_name`。I need know the type of `date`

2.I guess the type date is timestamp.

3.total_count he done:

`select count(1) from table_name where user_id=1231 and date between '2021-03-01' and '2021-04-01';`

4.group by status

`select count(1),status from table_name where user_id=123 and date between '2021-03-01' and '2021-04-01' group by status`

Comment: if you can solve the problem,please vote for me.thanks

Comment: Note that `count(1)` is actually (a bit) slower than `count(*)` in case you fell for the urban myth than `count(1)` is faster